# Call a function multiple times and get a list of results

Tags: ruby, function, dictionary, reduce

I want to call the function `f` 5 times (for instance) and get a list of results. Right now I have this:

```
(1..5).to_a.map!{f}
```

Note: Right now `f` is a function that takes no input and returns `true` or `false`. So when this is done running, I get a list of 5 `true`/`false` values.

Is there a better way to do this using other built in functions (possibly `reduce`? I had that idea but cannot figure out how to use it...)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
5.times.collect { f }
```

(Assuming no parameters. `map` is an alias to `collect`; I prefer the name `collect` when actually collecting as it seems more communicative, but YMMV.)

I also prefer the longer `5.times` instead of `(1..5)`. This seems more communicative: I'm not really "iterating over a range", I'm "doing something five times".

IMO the answer is slightly counter-intuitive in this case, since I'm not really running `collect` five times, but `collect.5.times { f }` doesn't work, so we play a bit of a mental game anyway.

Comment: wow... how did i miss that! thanks @Dave Newton, exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Try the block form of the Array constructor if you want zero based increasing arguments:

```
Array.new(5) {|x| (x+1).to_f} # => [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
Array.new(10) { rand } # => [0.794129655156092, ..., 0.794129655156092]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just shorten your code by not putting `to_a` ... (1..5) is an enumerable so it works with map.

`(1..5).map!{f}`

Answer (score 1):

## Use Array.new with a block

```
Array.new(10) { f }
```

The index value is available if you want it:

```
Array.new(10) { |i| f(i) }
```

[From the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-c-new):

> [With a block], an array of the given size is created. Each element in this array is created by passing the element’s index to the given block and storing the return value.

This has been possible since [at least 1.8.7](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-c-new).